# Gradle aar library dependecy in module: failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm a newbie with gradle and I'm having a dependecy problem. I have the follow project structure:

```
-MyApp
-MyAppLibrary
-MyAppPro
-MyAppFree
-ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper
--libs\ThirdPartyLibrary.aar
```

Both `MyAppPro` and `MyAppFree` depend on `MyAppLibrary`, which depends on `ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper`. As the name suggests, `ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper` is a wrapper on an external library, namely `ThirdPartyLibrary.aar`.

This is my configuration:

**build.gradle MyAppPro**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':MyAppLibrary')
}
```

**build.gradle MyAppLibrary**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

**build.gradle ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
         }
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'volley.jar')
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'

}
```

When gradle sync completes, I have got this error:

```
MyApp/MyAppFre/ build.gradle: failed to resolve ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0
MyApp/MyAppLibrary/ build.gradle: failed to resolve ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0
MyApp/MyAppPro/ build.gradle: failed to resolve ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0
```

Can someone help me figure out where is the issue?

Comment: Try to remove the `-` char in the name of aar. Try to use `ThirdPartyLibrary_0.1.0` changing the name in the libs folder and in the gradle file.

Comment: Still not working. Please consider that ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper build is successful, I think that the problem arise while  being imported in others modules.

Comment: Try to aAdd the same compile(name: 'ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0', ext: 'aar') with the right folder, in the other modules (MyAppLibrary...)

Comment: I already test this solution and it works, but in such case I will broke my logic... and have no sense to have a librarywrapper (which I need to have anyway )

Comment: The problem is that MyAppLibrary doesn't know where ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0:aar is. For this reason you have to specify the repository where you can find it. It works in the same way for all dependencies.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The other projects are seeing that the `:ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper` project depends on an artifact called `ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0:aar`. Java (and Android) libraries do not bundle their own dependencies together - instead, they simply publish a list of their dependencies. The consuming project is then responsible for loading not only the library it directly depends on, but all of the libraries *that library* depends on.

The net effect of this is that `:MyAppFree` is loading in `:ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper`, then seeing that `:ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper` depends on `ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0:aar` and so thus trying to load that in as well. However, `:MyAppFree` doesn't know where `ThirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0:aar` lives.. and so it fails.

The solution will be to place similar `repositories` blocks in all your other projects. Try this:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs project(':ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper').file('libs')
    }
}
```

Using the `project(...).file(...)` method will free you from having to hardcode paths, and will instead use the Gradle DSL to resolve the filesystem path by looking up the project and having it do the resolution dynamically.

Comment: Volley.jar is bundled in ThirdPartyLibrary.aar. Unluckily grandle seems not to include .aar file: `Warning:Project thirdPartyLibraryWrapper: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: /MyApp/thirdPartyLibraryWrapper/libs/thirdPartyLibrary-0.1.0.aar`

Comment: So you are correct! Did some more tinkering and found a solution that works; answer updated.

Comment: thanks for detailed description about how dependencies works. It is possible to do a bundle with ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper and ThirdPartyLibrary? I think that I will prefer this solution in order to not break my actual  logic

Comment: It is possible, but it is not simple or easy - it involves the [shadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) or [fatJar](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin) plugins, and can result in dependency version conflicts that are very hard to find and resolve. Take a peek at the Gradle User Guide's chapter on [Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/1.8-rc-1/userguide/dependency_management.html), specifically section 50.2.2, for more info.

Comment: Does the `ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper` project actually add anything, or is it there solely to give the other projects access to `ThirdPartyLibrary`? If that is the case then it is unnecessary, and you can just put the `ThirdPartyLibrary` in a root `libs/` dir and have the other projects reference it directly.

Comment: `ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper` adds some boilerplate to `ThirdPartyLibrary` which however is used only in `ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper` and not in other modules.

Comment: Hi @evi, hate to be a nag but if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark under the arrows to the left of it. That will bubble it up in search results and help others find it! Thanks :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work